# Считывание файла с помощью итераторов

Tags: c++, итераторы

Можно ли сделать следующее без использования классических циклов и счётчиков, а с помощью итераторов?

Сначала считать значения из файла обычным оператором `<<` (конфигурационные переменные), потом, начиная с текущего места в файле, считать n значений в вектор с помощью итератора на текущий элемент и продвинутого итератора на n элементов. В конце считать остаток в другой вектор.

Как я себе это представляю (в файле строка `1 2 3 4 5`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>


int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    int first;
    file >> first;

    std::cout << "First: " << first << '\n';

    std::vector<int> next{std::istream_iterator<int>(file), std::next(std::istream_iterator<int>(file), 2)};

    std::cout << "Next 2 elements: ";
    std::copy(next.begin(), next.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<int> rest{std::istream_iterator<int>(file), std::istream_iterator<int>()};

    std::cout << "Rest: ";
    std::copy(rest.begin(), rest.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Однако вектора оказываются пустыми. Если не использовать вектор `next`, то `rest` выведется правильно, так что проблема думаю в `std::next()` -- он не просто продвигает итератор, но и продвигает файловый указатель. Можно ли как то добиться желаемого?

**UPD**

Разобрался, почему не работает.

1) "The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented, not when it is dereferenced. The first object is read when the iterator is constructed. Dereferencing only returns a copy of the most recently read object."

2) "Two stream iterators are equal if both of them are end-of-stream iterators or both of them refer to the same stream."

Вариант с сохранением итератора от @AR Hovsepyan также не работает из-за 2), хоть итераторы указывают на правильные элементы.

Можно ли сделать это как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream file{"test.txt"};
        file << "1 2 3 4 5";
    }

    std::ifstream file{"test.txt"};

    int first = 0;
    file >> first;

    std::cout << "First: " << first << '\n';

    std::vector<int> next(2);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{file}, 2, next.begin());

    std::cout << "Next 2 elements: ";
    std::copy(next.begin(), next.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<int> rest{std::istream_iterator<int>{file}, {}};

    std::cout << "Rest: ";
    std::copy(rest.begin(), rest.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

Ваш код не работает из за реализаци [`std::istream_iterator::operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator_cmp):

> Checks whether both lhs and rhs are equal. Two stream iterators are
>   equal if both of them are end-of-stream iterators or both of them
>   refer to the same stream.

Два итаратора равны если они оба EOF или **оба ссылаются на один поток**.

Таким образом следующий код всегда будет выводить `true`

```
std::ifstream file{"test.txt"};
std::istream_iterator<int> it{file};    
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (it == std::next(it, 2)) << std::endl; //true
```

и следовательно интервал [it, it + 2) всегда пуст

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, почему не работает. А про `std::copy_n()` забыл, он тут идеально подходит!